# Org #+INCLUDE: turning what I want to be a 2nd level header into a 1st level header

Tags: org-mode, org-export, htmlize

Test case:

`a.org`

```
* This is a big section

  I have some content here

** And a second level section

   And more content here

*** And a third level section

    And more content here
```

`b.org`

```
** I have another second level section

   These files in my real world case are supposed to be split by date

*** You can see that

    [[In the repository][https://gitlab.com/srnb/notes]]

*** The actual real world case can be seen

    [[In the two APUSH sections][https://gitlab.com/srnb/notes/tree/master/AP%20US%20History]]
```

`main.org`

```
#+INCLUDE: a.org
#+INCLUDE: b.org
```

Resulting output when exported to HTML is that `I have another second level section` is a top level section.

Real world case: [GitLab/srnb/notes@master/AP US History](https://gitlab.com/srnb/notes/tree/master/AP%20US%20History)

Real world output: [m.s5.pm/notes/AP US History](https://m.s5.pm/AP%20US%20History)

The second file, `2019-08-20-NeoEuropean-Colonies.org`, is the one with the second level header.

The script that generates the big Org files with all the includes is `.deploy.sh` in the repository's root; it can be run locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `:minlevel` option on the `#+INCLUDE:` line to get `b.org` to start at the second level (the corollary is that you might as well not worry about the levels in `b.org` itself):

`main.org`:

```
#+INCLUDE: a.org
#+INCLUDE: b.org :minlevel 2
```

`b.org`:

```
* I have another second level section 

  ... but that is set through the #+INCLUDE directive in the parent file. This file can pretend that its top level headline is a level-1 headline.

   These files in my real world case are supposed to be split by date

** You can see that

    [[https://gitlab.com/srnb/notes][In the repository]]

** The actual real world case can be seen

    [[https://gitlab.com/srnb/notes/tree/master/AP%20US%20History][In the two APUSH sections]]
```

BTW, your links are backwards (I fixed them in my version): they should have the form `[[URL][Description]]`.

Comment: Ahaha thanks I don't normally use links in Org :^( I'll need to edit my `.deploy.sh` to add the `:minlevel` option by counting asterisks, I hope it won't be that hard.